# How to check two times in a time range using php

Tags: php, time

I have two times like start_time and end_time and also having a time range like a start time and a end time. I want to check start_time and end_time are in the range of start time and end time or not. How to check that.

```
$start_time1 = 10:15 am; //! time table start time
$end_time1 = 12:30 pm;   //! time table end time

$strattime2 = 10:00 am; //! time range - start time
$endtime2 = 1:00 pm;   //! time range - end time
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the boundary of the range. The query must be started on or after the range and must be ended on or before the range ends. So

```
function check($queryStart, $queryEnd, $rangeStart, $rangeEnd) {
    return ($queryStart >= $rangeStart && $queryEnd <= $rangeEnd);
}
```

If you want to check whether the query is overlapping the range or not, you should check whether the query ends before the range start or the query starts after the range end.

```
function overlap($queryStart, $queryEnd, $rangeStart, $rangeEnd) {
    return !($queryEnd < $rangeStart || $queryStart > $rangeEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> you may convert all the times to `DateTime()` Objects and then check the  difference like so:

```
    <?php   

        function startStopTimeIsWithinRange($startTime='10:15', $stopTime='12:30') {                
            $dateStart      = new DateTime('2016-10-30 ' . $startTime);     //<== IGNORE, THE DATE. NOTICE THE TIME
            $dateStop       = new DateTime('2016-10-30 ' . $stopTime);      //<== IGNORE, THE DATE. NOTICE THE TIME

            $rangeStart     = new DateTime('2016-10-30 10:00');             //<== IGNORE, THE DATE. NOTICE THE TIME
            $rangeStop      = new DateTime('2016-10-30 13:00');             //<== IGNORE, THE DATE. NOTICE THE TIME

            if($dateStart >= $rangeStart && $rangeStop >= $dateStop){
                return true;
            }
            return false;               
        }

        var_dump( startStopTimeIsWithinRange('10:15', '12:30')  );           //<== NOTICE THE COLON (:) AND NOT DOT (.)
```